# Do you know why this code updates the last data only?

Tags: java, mysql, json, hibernate

'seikyuDataList' is parameter for this function and I want to update each data of 'billingInfoNumber' in 'seikyuDataList' but it is updated only the last value in 'jDemandArrObj.get("number")'. I checked the data changing in Debug Mode and also I checked the query data in log. Every data was right but same value only in database.

Do you guys know how to fix this?

```
        jBodyObj = (JSONObject)jParser.parse(response.getBody());
        JSONArray jDemandArr = (JSONArray)jBodyObj.get("demand");

        for(int i = 0; i < jDemandArr.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject jDemandArrObj = (JSONObject)jDemandArr.get(i);
            JTSeikyuData seikyuData = seikyuDataList.get(i);

            if(jDemandArrObj.get("error_code") != null) {
                apiResultCode = jDemandArrObj.get("error_code").toString();
                apiResultMsg = this.getErrorMessage(apiResultCode);
                jDemandArrObj.put("error_message", apiResultMsg);
                jDemandArrObj.put("billing_code", seikyuData.getBillingCode());
            }else {
                apiResultCode = "0000";
                apiResultMsg = "";
                billingInfoNumber = jDemandArrObj.get("number").toString(); 
                seikyuData.setBillingInfoNumber(billingInfoNumber);
            }

            seikyuData.setApiResultCode(apiResultCode);
            seikyuData.setApiResultMsg(apiResultMsg);
            if(resendingFlg) {
                seikyuDataService.updateResendingData(seikyuData);
            }else {
                seikyuDataService.updateApiResult(seikyuData);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sounds like either your `seikyuDataList` contains N references to the same `JTSeikyuData` object, *or* the fields of the `JTSeikyuData` class are `static`.